# How to set limit and character length in input type number?

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code that sets the range value from 1-5.

```
$(document).on('keyup','#getScore',function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('value');
    if($(this).val() > 5 ){
        $(this).val(a);
    }
})
```

Now I also want to set the number of digits to 1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this, trying to get a correct digit from the input or else putting a valid one instead:

```js
$(document).on('input','#getScore',function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a.length > 1)
        a = a.replace(/[^1-5]/g, '').substr(-1);
    $(this).val(a > 5 ? 5 : a < 1 ? 1 : a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="getScore">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(document).on('keyup','#getScore',function(){ 
    var a = $(this).val(); 
    if(a.length> 1 &&  $(this).val() > 5) {   
 // Your code
     }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add if ($(this).val().length > 1)

Comment: I think instead of onkeyup i will use onkeypress.

Answer (score 0):

if your value is integer means, `val.length` need to be  string.. use `.toString()` before getting length.

```js
$(document).on('keyup','#getScore',function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('value');
    if($(this).val() > 5 && $(this).val().toString().length > 1 ){
        $(this).val(a);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set with `min` and `max` value attribute and find the value length greater then one .apply `% 10 %5` its with convert to `1-5` .surely never exist `2` digit not go with above `5` . And user for `a% 10 % 5 == 0 ? 1 : a% 10 % 5` ternary operator its control with `1-5`

```js
$(document).on('keyup','#getScore',function(){
    var a = $(this).val()
    if($(this).val().length > 1 ){
      a = a < 0 ? a*-1 : a; //for negative number 
            $(this).val(a% 10 % 5 == 0 ? 1 : a% 10 % 5);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="getScore" type="number" min="0" max="5">
```

Comment: how about negative numbers?

Comment: i want my input type will return false if the length is more than 1

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, if you're trying to restrict an input between the numbers 1-5, why not just use a number input?

```
<form>
  Quantity (between 1 and 5):
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
</form>
```